# How do you find if a number is within a range in Java? Problems with Math.abs(num1-num2) <= inRange

Tags: java, math

I've seen in another question that the solution to finding if your number is in a range was,

```
Math.abs(num1-num2) <= inRange
```

Where inRange is the number you are trying to figure out if it is in range between num2 and num1.

Where this formula breaks for me is when I insert these numbers.

```
Math.abs(25-(-25)) <= -5
```

I'm trying to find if -5 is in between -25 and 25. This equation is false even though the answer is true, -5 falls between -25 and 25.

Please clarify for me!

Comment: the formula definitely looks buggy. Just curious, if you have the bounds as well as the number, can't you just do a simple condition (a <= n <= b) ? I mean, is there a point in these computations vis-a-vis a direct comparison that I am missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use `Math.abs` at all. I'd use:

```
if (lowerBound <= value && value < upperBound)
```

or

```
if (lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound)
```

if you want the upper bound to be inclusive too.

Indeed, the `Math.abs()` approach seems *entirely* broken - I strongly suspect that you misunderstood the question where it was posed as a solution.

Answer (score 8):

For bonus points, there is a new [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class (used with helper class [Ranges](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ranges.html)) introduced in Guava 10.x:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import com.google.common.collect.Ranges;

public class RangeTest {

    Range<Integer> range = Ranges.closed(-25, +25);

    public boolean rangeTest(Integer candidate) {
        return range.contains(candidate);
    }

}


public class TestMain {
    static RangeTest rangeTest = new RangeTest();

    public static void doTest(Integer candidate) {
        System.out.println(candidate + " in -25..+25: "
                + rangeTest.rangeTest(candidate));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doTest(-26);
        doTest(-25);
        doTest(-24);
        doTest(-1);
        doTest(-0);
        doTest(+1);
        doTest(+24);
        doTest(+25);
        doTest(+26);
    }

}
```

Output:

-26 in -25..+25: false
-25 in -25..+25: true
-24 in -25..+25: true
-1 in -25..+25: true
0 in -25..+25: true
1 in -25..+25: true
24 in -25..+25: true
25 in -25..+25: true
26 in -25..+25: false

The Range class supports open and closed ranges, ranges from -INF to +INF, and all sorts of range-related operations like membership, intersection, and span.

Comment: Since Guava 14 you should use static methods on `Range` itself to instantiate `Range`s (`Ranges` was deprecated), e.g. `Range.closed(-25, +25)`.

Answer (score 7):

Just do:

```
bool isInRange = Math.min(num1,num2) <= inRange 
                && Math.max(num1,num2) >= inRange;
```

Your current approach just checks number ranges. in fact smallest and largest number distance.

Answer (score 2):

Below expression will check `x` is between `a` and `b`:

```
Math.abs(x - a) + Math.abs(b - x) == Math.abs(b - a)
```

Comment: Your way is tricky, but it's not a way to use in development, it's not clear in first glance, and should prove it, so it's better to use more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however the Math.abs method can be clearer depending what you're working on, and is still worth showing:

```
int x = 5;
int bounds = 25;
if(Math.abs(x) <= bounds) {
    //run if x is anywhere between -25 and 25
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin has .. operator

```
if (center.x in 0..MaxX) {
                   //Do stuff
}
if (center.y !in 0..MaxY) {
                    //Do stuff
}
```