# How to perform range comparison for integer in java eg .x>a<y

Tags: java, integer

How to perform range comparison for integer in java eg .x>a

eg . i want to check if my integer a falls between range x and y

a>30 and a<40

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already did that. What is your question ?

Comment: `if((a > 30) && (a < 40)) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: @ANS I think he asks for the correct syntax as some languages use keywords like `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret Yes. Just added my answer :)

Comment: Better to google your question first man:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976744/how-do-you-find-if-a-number-is-within-a-range-in-java-problems-with-math-absnu

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. If you struggling to put the correct syntax, just convert that `and` to `&&`

```
  int a = 35; // for ex
    if(a>30 && a<40) {
      // yes do something please 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment , what meant was  something like 30>a<40 . Is this possible ?

Comment: @SelvaKumarKrishnamoorthy No. Not possible in Java.:)

Answer (score 0):

You said that! You must use the logical AND operator like this:

```
if(a > x && a > y)
{
    // do something;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Davide , what meant was something like 30>a<40 . Is this possible in java ?

Comment: In that case I don't think there is a way to do it. Java syntax needs logical operators to perform such comparison chains, but, in my opinion, it is not a big deal :)